# IONIC 6 Capacitor Android & iOS app and Azure AD auth open in external browser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, capacitor

I develop in Ionic 6 framework, Angular and Capacitor an App for Android & iOS. I would like to do authentication with Microsoft's Azure AD without using Auth Connect module.I have integrated the example code at this link into my app:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-angular-auth-code

The app start with homepage and when I click on login button the code open Microsoft link in an external browser (example Chrome or Firefox).
I do the login and when it was successful it sends me back in external browser with url localhost:8100 and it doesn't go any further. I would like to ask if someone can help me to integrate the login function inside the app without going back to the localhost but to the home page of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the MSAL Angular/Javascript library is not working for Capacitor or Cordova Apps, but you can use this library [Capacitor-Oauth2](https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-oauth2)

You need to follow all steps for configuration on the Android and iOS platform (I use this library for App Proxy authorization and don't have problems today), or the official MSAL Android and iOS native library.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact I decided to change the library and use the native MSAL one and it works!

Comment: Yes, of course it will work, but it is not the best way to implement it, it is better to have a HYBRID implementation... :)